# C# Always make the return type that of the current class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I built a query builder based on some entities using generics. I want to have a certain syntax that looks like this:

```cs
Repository.Objects.Where
    .State.Equals(ObjectState.Created)
    .ParentId.Equals(new ObjectId(0))
    .GetAsync();
```

The `Where` Property returns a query builder object that contains the single properties of an object that you can compare to something. Now the issue is that `Object` is just the base type and you might want to query for more specific properties, so I thought it would be nice to have a syntax like this:

```cs
Repository.Objects.Where.AsObjectSystem
    .RequiredFactors.Equals(AuthenticationFactor.Password) 
    .State.Equals(ObjectState.Created)
    .ParentId.Equals(new ObjectId(0))
    .GetAsync();
```

RequiredFactors is a property from `ObjectSystem` but for everytime I want to call a property from that I need to call `AsObjectSystem` again which is not desired at all, which is where my problem lies. First the code:

```cs
public interface IQueryBuilderObject : IQueryBuilder<IQueryBuilderObject, Object, IObjectCollection>
{
    IPropertyFilterIdentifier<IQueryBuilderObject, ObjectId> Id { get; }

    IPropertyFilterIdentifier<IQueryBuilderObject, ObjectId> ParentId { get; }

    IPropertyFilterIdentifier<IQueryBuilderObject, ObjectId> TemplateId { get; }

    IPropertyFilterIdentifier<IQueryBuilderObject, UserId> EditorId { get; }

    IPropertyFilterString<IQueryBuilderObject> InternalId { get; }

    IPropertyFilterString<IQueryBuilderObject> ExternalId { get; }

    IPropertyFilterString<IQueryBuilderObject> Description { get; }

    IPropertyFilterEnum<IQueryBuilderObject, ObjectState> State { get; }

    IPropertyFilterString<IQueryBuilderObject> ObjectClass { get; }

    IPropertyFilterString<IQueryBuilderObject> DisplayNameShort { get; }

    IPropertyFilterString<IQueryBuilderObject> DisplayNameLong { get; }

    IQueryBuilderObjectSystem AsObjectSystem { get; }
}
```

```cs
public interface IQueryBuilderObjectSystem : IQueryBuilderObject
{
    IQueryBuilderObjectSystem And(Action<IQueryBuilderObjectSystem> queryBuilder);

    IQueryBuilderObjectSystem Or(Action<IQueryBuilderObjectSystem> queryBuilder);

    IPropertyFilterEnum<IQueryBuilderObjectSystem, AuthenticationFactor> RequiredFactors { get; }

    IQueryBuilderObjectSystemSubSystem AsSubSystem { get; }

    IQueryBuilderObjectSystemSystemGroup AsSystemGroup { get; }

    IQueryBuilderObjectSystemIoSystem AsIoSystem { get; }

    IQueryBuilderObjectSystemContainer AsContainer { get; }

    IQueryBuilderObjectSystemApplication AsApplication { get; }
}
```

```cs
public interface IPropertyFilter<TQueryBuilder, TEntityType> : IPropertyFilter
    where TQueryBuilder : IQueryBuilder
{
    IPropertyFilter<TQueryBuilder, TEntityType> Not { get; }

    TQueryBuilder Equals(TEntityType value);

    TQueryBuilder Null();
}
```

The `IPropertyFilter...` properties are the deciding factor here. The first generic determines what type of `IQueryBuilder` they will return. So the ones from `IQueryBuilderObject` will only return their own type and so does `IQueryBuilderObjectSystem`. As soon as I call a property from `IQueryBuilderObject` the `AsObjectSystem` needs to be repeated.

I want those `IPropertyFilter...` to always return the value of the current class. Note that the hierarchy goes down 3 levels and might get more later on, e.g.:

Object > ObjectSystem > ObjectSystemSubSystem

Edit: Added the IPropertyFilter interface

As you can see the return type of the Equals, Null and all the other operators equals the first generic value. I want this to be the type of the class where this object got created.

Also sorry I wasn't clear enough earlier: Point of this is that I can't use LINQ to iterate a SQL database with sometimes 100,000 lines and more just for a simple request like looking up for an Id. I basically convert the built query to SQL using an SQL builder I built but that's not the point here.

TL;DR: I need to make a SQL query from this

Comment: Why not use more generics?

Comment: That's where I'm stuck. I just can't figure out how.

Comment: I think you are reinventing the wheel here. Why not use the existing LINQ operators?

Comment: @Marty perhaps to try and avoid lambda overhead?

Comment: Can you show some declarations for operators like `Equals`?

Comment: @NetMage: I'm not sure what you you mean by lambda overhead... The overhead needed to implement  and maintain a separate solution will most likely be bigger. E.g. OP's first example might look simple as `Repository.Objects.Where(o => o.State == ObjectState.Created && o.ParentId == 0)`. You'll need to be more specific as to why this isn't good enough.

Comment: @Marty working with LINQ/EF I got nothing on the performance front, but working in `IEnumerable` I can see where you could be removing the lambda calling overhead.

Comment: @NetMage I guess you're right; but I still have my reservations if the way OP would want to tackle it (more abstract&complex) will not bring the gain you might have in mind when you're speaking of performance gains. Also I fear that this all might lead to a form of [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)...

Comment: This thing here is backed by a SQL table and should not do unnecessary requests. It can also be backed by something else, but fact is that I am not able to just iterate the data to check.

Comment: But that brings up @marty 's question why reinvent the already available LINQ to SQL/EF translation wheel? C# had the entire `Expression` classes added to enable programmatically translating lambda's to SQL.

Comment: Possibly because I didn't know it existed. I'm taking a look at that right now.